# Iodine solution concentration

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions, concentration, halogens

I am planning to make 1L of 0.005M iodine solution from KI and I2. I have found instructions that say to use 2 g of KI and 1.3 g of I2 but no explanation why exactly this particular amount. I also found that iodine solution concentration will be the same as the concentration of the added I2, again no explanation.
Could someone please explaine the calculations behind this? What and how affects the final concentration? Since there is a reaction happening (KI + I2 = KI3), I am a little confused.

Comment: Iodine has relatively poor solubility in water, but dissolves much more readily in an aqueous solution containing iodide ions because tri-iodide ions are formed. So the KI just facilitates dissolution of the iodine in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{I2}$ has a molar mass of $254$ g/mol. $\ce{KI}$ has a molar mass of $39 + 127 = 166$ g/mol.

Then $1.3$ g $\ce{I2}$ is $\frac{1.3}{254} = 5.12$ millimole $\ce{I2}$.
Also $2$ g $\ce{KI}$ is $\frac{2.0}{166} = 12.05$ millimole $\ce{KI}$

Now $\ce{I2}$ is nearly insoluble in water. But it is soluble in $\ce{KI}$ solutions, thanks to the following equation. If the previous amounts of $\ce{I2}$ and $\ce{KI}$ are dissolved in $1$ liter water, the $5.12$ millimole $\ce{I2}$ are totally transformed into $\ce{KI3}$. The obtained solution contains $\ce{5.12}$ millimole $\ce{KI3}$, $12.05 - 5.12 = 6.97$ millimole $\ce{KI}$, and $0.0$ millimole $\ce{I2}$, because of the reaction : $$\ce{KI + I2 <=> KI3}$$ This reaction has been considered as complete in the previous calculations for reason of simplicity. But in reality this reaction is an equilibrium, whose equilibrium constant is unknown. So the concentration of $\ce{I2}$ in the $\ce{KI3}$ solution is not zero. It has a small and unknown value. But this value has no importance and nobody is interested in knowing it. The only important parameter in such a solution is the total amount of $\ce{I2 + KI3}$. Why is it so ?

The reason is that such a solution of $\ce{I2}$ in $\ce{KI}$ is used for titrating reducing solutions like thiosulfate ion $\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$ (or the reverse rection). If an unknown solution of iodine in $\ce{KI}$ is titrated with a standardized solution of thiosulfate, the solution of iodine is slowly discolored by the reaction : $$\ce{S2O3^{2-} + I2 -> S4O6^{2-} + 2 I-}$$ In the beginning the solution of $\ce{I2 + KI}$ is dark violet and contains very few free iodine $\ce{I2}$. This iodine is quickly destroyed by the first drops of thiosulfate. But as soon as it is destroyed by thiosulfate, $\ce{I2}$ is regenerated by $\ce{KI3}$ thanks to the equilibrium $\ce{KI + I2<=>KI3}$. So progressively the added ions thiosulfate destroy all the iodine contained in $\ce{I2 + KI3}$. If we know that the unknown solution contains $\ce{I2 + KI3}$ in unknown amount, this amount is equal to the number of mole of added  thiosulfate, up to the endpoint of the titration. And this endpoint is defined by the entire discoloration of the solution. This phenomena can be defined and observed with a high precision : ± $1$ drop of thiosulfate. It is one of the more precise titrations of the whole domain of analytical chemistry.

So when $\ce{I2}$ in a $\ce{KI}$ solution, we can ignore that $\ce{I2}$ is partly in the form of $\ce{KI3}$. The titration with $\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$ proceeds as if iodine is simply dissolved in the solution.